# CustomSolution Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: development, custom-list, email, splistitem

atm I'm implementing a custom solution in our SP 2010 farm to receive emails on an specific custom list.
With the following code it's possible to add one entry, with an email-body contains one line with values, seperated by ';' - i.e. (test;entry;in;our;sharepoint)
But now it's not cool, related to performance sending hundreds/thousands of mails in a minute to our sharepoint and insert every single item.
So I implemented in the same solution sth. to receive an email with multiple lines in a body (lines currently seperated by '~' and the single line still seperated by ';').
But there I can find the following error in the SharePoint log:

```
07/07/2015 12:02:56.85  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x13A4)                       0x07F0  SharePoint Foundation           E-Mail                          6873    Warning     An error occurred while processing the incoming e-mail file C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\15ed460901d0b89c00000008.eml. The error was: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..    ca05878c-e64b-4a32-bdf0-1916a8e8464a
```

And here's the code of my solution:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace incomail_proxylist.incomail
{
    public class incomail : SPEmailEventReceiver
    {
        public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, String receiverData)
        {
            base.EmailReceived(list, emailMessage, receiverData);
            string str = emailMessage.PlainTextBody;
            string booli = emailMessage.Headers["subject"];

            if (booli.Contains("COMPLETE_LIST"))
            {    
                string[] entries = str.Split('~'); //new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None
                for (int i = 0; i <= entries.Length; i++)
                {
                    SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();
                    string[] arr = entries[i].Split(';');

                    newItem["Title"] = arr[0];
                    newItem["Host"] = arr[1];
                    newItem["Internal_IP"] = arr[2];
                    newItem["External_IP"] = arr[3];
                    newItem["Incoming_URL"] = arr[4];
                    newItem["Forwarding_URL"] = arr[5];
                    newItem["SSL"] = arr[6];
                    newItem["Status"] = arr[7];
                    newItem["ConfigPath"] = arr[8];

                    newItem.Update();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();
                string[] arr = str.Split(';');

                newItem["Title"] = emailMessage.Headers["subject"];
                newItem["Host"] = arr[0];
                newItem["Internal_IP"] = arr[1];
                newItem["External_IP"] = arr[2];
                newItem["Incoming_URL"] = arr[3];
                newItem["Forwarding_URL"] = arr[4];
                newItem["SSL"] = arr[5];
                newItem["Status"] = arr[6];
                newItem["ConfigPath"] = arr[7];

                newItem.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
Adding an email like requested:

```
x-sender: server-a@domain.com
x-receiver: server-b@domain.com
Received: from exchange.domain.com ([ip of server]) by sharepoint.domain.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7600.16385);
     Tue, 7 Jul 2015 10:53:37 +0200
Received: from exchange2.domain.com (ip of server) by
 exchange.domain.com (ip of server) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id
 14.3.224.2; Tue, 7 Jul 2015 10:53:32 +0200
Received: from server-a.domain.com (ip of server) by
 exchange2.domain.com (ip of server) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
 14.3.224.2; Tue, 7 Jul 2015 10:53:32 +0200
Message-ID: <686044.912410097-sendEmail@server-a>
From: Server-A <server-a@domain.com>
To: "server-b@domain.com" <server-b@domain.com>
Subject: COMPLETE_LIST
Date: Tue, 7 Jul 2015 08:53:32 +0000
X-Mailer: sendEmail-1.56
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="----MIME delimiter for sendEmail-943467.83247693"
Return-Path: server-a@domain.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 07 Jul 2015 08:53:37.0598 (UTC) FILETIME=[69F27DE0:01D0B892]

------MIME delimiter for sendEmail-943467.83247693
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

title;server-a.domain.com;ip1;ip2;incomingURL;forwardingURL;active;/path/to/config-file~
title;server-a.domain.com;ip1;ip2;incomingURL;forwardingURL;active;/path/to/config-file~
title;server-a.domain.com;ip1;ip2;incomingURL;forwardingURL;active;/path/to/config-file~
title;server-a.domain.com;ip1;ip2;incomingURL;forwardingURL;active;/path/to/config-file~
title;server-a.domain.com;ip1;ip2;incomingURL;forwardingURL;active;/path/to/config-file~
title;server-a.domain.com;ip1;ip2;incomingURL;forwardingURL;active;/path/to/config-file~
title;server-a.domain.com;ip1;ip2;incomingURL;forwardingURL;active;/path/to/config-file~
title;server-a.domain.com;ip1;ip2;incomingURL;forwardingURL;active;/path/to/config-file~

------MIME delimiter for sendEmail-943467.83247693--
```

This is an example for an email like our exchange receives it.
I hided our internal information like IPs and hostnames.
But the structure is exactly the same!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide one of your emails.

Comment: eMail code is provided above.. Just hided internal information like ips, hostnames, URLs - the strucutre is exactly the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample email, **you are missing the "SSL" portion within your input**.

When you are splitting the `entries` into `arr` you are only getting back 8 items rather than 9. Attempting to access `arr[8]` when it doesn't exist will cause *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*.

You should add some validation regarding length on the split lines. Something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
{
    string[] arr = entries[i].Split(';');
    if(arr.Length == 9)
    {
        SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();

        newItem["Title"] = arr[0];
        newItem["Host"] = arr[1];
        newItem["Internal_IP"] = arr[2];
        newItem["External_IP"] = arr[3];
        newItem["Incoming_URL"] = arr[4];
        newItem["Forwarding_URL"] = arr[5];
        newItem["SSL"] = arr[6];
        newItem["Status"] = arr[7];
        newItem["ConfigPath"] = arr[8];

        newItem.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my code but before I can query the if(arr.Lenght == 9) I have to create this arr :p So now in my for loop at first the arr will be created and then the if query will be done. But this doesn't solve my issue - in SP log there's still the error which i provided above..

Comment: @Flaash whoops! I've edited my code above. Were you able to confirm if you are missing the proper number of fields in the multiline emails?

Comment: Also, I just realized you are doing an <= in the for loop. Change this to just < (see above) and things should start working (assuming you send the right number of fields in your email).

Comment: damn. I was so fixed, the problem should be in my custom solution, so I haven't done a look in my bash script :D Now I adjusted the script and writes the "SSL-varable" in my email and now it works. Thanks for the help! In future I should read with open eyes :D Have a nice day :)